# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TP10000' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create database APU

create table STUDENT
(
Stud_Id varchar(50), 
Name varchar (50),
Major varchar (50),
Age int identity not null
)

select*
from STUDENT



insert into STUDENT values ('TP10000','Jamal','Economy','21')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP15000','Putih','Communicatio','19')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP20000' , 'Bakar' ,'Economy', '25')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP25000' , 'Gibson','Management','24')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP35000',  'Rohaya','Computer Science','20')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP40000','Remi','Business','19')


create table student2
(
Stud_Id varchar(50), 
Name varchar (50),
Major varchar (50),
Age int identity not null
)

select*
from STUDENT       
select*
from student

when i execute this part 

insert into STUDENT values ('TP10000','Jamal','Economy','21')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP15000','Putih','Communicatio','19')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP20000' , 'Bakar' ,'Economy', '25')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP25000' , 'Gibson','Management','24')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP35000',  'Rohaya','Computer Science','20')
insert into STUDENT values ('TP40000','Remi','Business','19')
```

i get this error please help me

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'TP10000' to data type int.

Comment: Welcome to SO - please format your code, to make it easier for others to read.

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TP10000' to data type int.` - You can't convert a varchar to an integer, the error says it...

Comment: Am sure you would have got this error `An explicit value for the identity column in table 'STUDENT' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON` not the one you have mentioned. You are trying to insert into identity column that is the only mistake i found

Comment: It depends on the sql-server version.

Comment: Your problem is because you have added an `identity` column on your table `Age int identity not null` in all versions of sql server an `identity` column will have an auto generated value and in some versions it will be ordered as the first column in an `insert statement` without the column list therefore your error lies on you trying to add a varchar `'TP10000'` on an int column. Create your age columns as `Age int not null` and see if it works. Then I will add an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back... but i tried its not working it still gives  me that error :(